# Excel to html export

Tags: javascript, html, excel

While I'm exporting data from excel to html it's exporting the table like this

```
    <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=1438 
    style='border-collapse:
    collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:1078pt'>
```

is it somehow possible to add attribute:

```
   class="table table-bordered table-condensed"
```

to already exported data?

I'm asking because I have JS function that is highlighting rows into different color while clicked, but it requires the link to table class. Or maybe there is some other way to link JS with table?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simple jQuery will do.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('table').addClass("table table-bordered table-condensed");

});
```

Comment: That's what i was looking for. Thanks! I've got one more question. Is there a simple way to store those highlighted rows? I mean while I will close the page and reopen it, cells that were highlighted would be also highlighted. And if I highlight some cells and someone else on other computer will open the page the cells will stay highlighted.

Comment: @Karol depends on how you are highlighting them.  Chances are it is a bit more complicated, because javascript (and hence jQuery) is only temporary! Technically, it maybe could be feasible with help of AJAX, but still probably not optimal. Also you probably should create a separate question for that though...

Answer (score 1):

hello  i  create  one simple html  page that convert  excle file  and show that data in html   in tabel  format.
[you can check the  code](https://codepen.io/Parthis/pen/XWqdKje)

```js
const excel_file = document.getElementById('excel_file');

excel_file.addEventListener('change', (event) => {

  if (!['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/vnd.ms-excel'].includes(event.target.files[0].type)) {
    document.getElementById('excel_data').innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Only .xlsx or .xls file format are allowed</div>';

    excel_file.value = '';

    return false;
  }

  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);

  reader.onload = function(event) {

    var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);

    var work_book = XLSX.read(data, {
      type: 'array'
    });

    var sheet_name = work_book.SheetNames;

    var sheet_data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(work_book.Sheets[sheet_name[0]], {
      header: 1
    });

    if (sheet_data.length > 0) {
      var table_output = '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">';

      for (var row = 0; row < sheet_data.length; row++) {

        table_output += '<tr>';

        for (var cell = 0; cell < sheet_data[row].length; cell++) {

          if (row == 0) {

            table_output += '<th>' + sheet_data[row][cell] + '</th>';

          } else {

            table_output += '<td>' + sheet_data[row][cell] + '</td>';

          }

        }

        table_output += '</tr>';

      }

      table_output += '</table>';

      document.getElementById('excel_data').innerHTML = table_output;
    }

    excel_file.value = '';

  }

});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script async='async' src='//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js'></script>
  <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
      google_ad_client: "ca-pub-4529508631166774",
      enable_page_level_ads: true
    });
  </script>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Webslesson Demo | How to Display Excel Data in HTML Table using JavaScript</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.15.1/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header"><b>Select Excel File</b></div>
      <div class="card-body">

        <input type="file" id="excel_file" />

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="excel_data" class="mt-5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it at run-time.

```
var element = document.getElementById("table");
element.classList.add("table");
element.classList.add("table-bordered");
element.classList.add("table-condensed");
```

Depending on how many tables you have, the selector may need to change.